# Button "clear" on a TextBox line appears only once

Tags: c#, winforms

I managed to get a clear button on a TextBox line with little code. This deletes the corresponding line and itself when clicking. But the button appears only once. It should be generated with each click on each additional line. Can someone help me there? Many Thanks.

Is WinForm VS2010 C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Daten_zu_TextBox_Test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.Name = "btn";
        btn1.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click);
        btn1.Size = new Size(18, 18);
        btn1.Text = "X";
        btn1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        textBox1.Controls.Add(btn1);

        string sent = ("\t" + "Testline1");

        textBox1.AppendText(sent);
        textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Controls.Clear();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(1, textBox1.Lines[0].Length + 0 );
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(0, textBox1.Lines[0].Length + 0);
    }

  }
}
```

[image]

```
private int ButtonCount2 = 0;
private int Btn2Y = 18;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn2 = new Button();
    btn2.Name = "btn2" + ButtonCount2;
    btn2.Click += new EventHandler(btn2_Click);
    btn2.Size = new Size(18, 18);
    btn2.Location = new Point(1, Btn2Y * ButtonCount2);

    ButtonCount2++;

    btn2.Text = "X";
    btn2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    textBox2.Controls.Add(btn2);

    string sent = ("\t" + "Testline" + ButtonCount2);

    textBox2.AppendText(sent);
    textBox2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}
void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bt2 = sender as Button;
    var bt2Id = textBox2.Controls.IndexOf(bt2);
    textBox2.Controls.Remove(bt2);
    var lines = textBox2.Text.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split('\n').ToList();
    lines.RemoveAt(bt2Id);
    textBox2.Text = string.Join("\r\n", lines);

    foreach (Button btn2 in textBox2.Controls)
    {
        var Id2 = int.Parse(btn2.Name.Replace("btn2", ""));

        if (Id2 > bt2Id)
        {
            var b2 = textBox2.Controls.Find(btn2.Name, false)[0];
            var loc2 = btn2.Location;
            b2.Location = new Point(loc2.X, loc2.Y - Btn2Y);
         }
    }
    ButtonCount2--;
}
```

The second button looks like this.

Comment: can you post the output you got as image? little hard to understand your requirement

Comment: It looks like this. If the clear "X" button in the textbox line is pressed, the entire line is deleted with the button. But he only appears once. This should appear on each line so that each line can be deleted individually.

Comment: Do consider moving to a __proper__ control for this use case! A Listview comes to mind or maybe a DataGridView. TextBox is utterly useless for this kind of thing, as you should have noticed by now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is tested working codes. The button will coincide with text for the textbox font size being the default `8`.

```
private int ButtonCount = 0;
private int BtnY = 13;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn1 = new Button();
    btn1.Name = "btn" + ButtonCount;
    btn1.Click += new EventHandler(btn1_Click);
    btn1.Size = new Size(18, 18);
    btn1.Location = new Point(1, BtnY * ButtonCount);
    btn1.Tag = ButtonCount;  // the last edit

    ButtonCount++;

    btn1.Text = "X";
    btn1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    textBox1.Controls.Add(btn1);

    string sent = ("\t" + "Testline" + ButtonCount);

    textBox1.AppendText(sent);
    textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}

void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bt = sender as Button;
    var btId = textBox1.Controls.IndexOf(bt);
    textBox1.Controls.Remove(bt);
    var lines = textBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split('\n').ToList();
    lines.RemoveAt(btId);
    textBox1.Text = string.Join("\r\n", lines);

    foreach (Button btn in textBox1.Controls)
    {
        //var Id = int.Parse(btn.Name.Replace("btn", "")); // the last edit
        var Id = (int)btn.Tag;  // the last edit

        if (Id > btId)
        {
            var b = textBox1.Controls.Find(btn.Name, false)[0];
            var loc = btn.Location;
            b.Location = new Point(loc.X, loc.Y - BtnY);
        }
    }
    ButtonCount--;
}
```

Comment: `@L_J and Hiren Patel`, Thank's for the further solutions. I still have the problem that the text is deleted in the wrong place. Each clear button should delete the text on the same line. Another problem is the empty lines that are result when deleting. They should be  postponed so, that are all lines to gether.

Comment: @JaDoLo  I edited the codes. Now it should work as you described.

Comment: `@L_J` Thank you very much, that works very well. I've taken this for a second added item `button2_Click` and adjusted the numbering `ButtonCount1, btn1, Btn1Y` and `ButtonCount2, btn2, Btn2Y` But there are problems with that. Only one or the other is possible. Surely it's just something small.

Comment: It's a bit hard to say what could be the fix without seeing the codes. The one thing I suspect could be the `id` of button extracted from the `btn.Name`. if you changed the `btn.Name` you should have changed `var Id = int.Parse(btn.Name.Replace("btn", ""));` here too. So, to avoid this I edited codes a little bit and save the `id`into the `Tag` property of the control.

Comment: `@L_J`  I have attached the code, I can't me explain it yet.

Comment: For me the attached the code works fine. The only thing I need to change is `private int Btn2Y = 13;` instead of `18`. @JaDoLo What is the exact issue for you now?

Comment: The last edit shows the same behavior. When cliked the `button1` is coming btn1 correct, when cliked `button2` the btn2 coms only from the third click and then the program hangs up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177270/discussion-between-l-j-and-jadolo).

Comment: `@L_J` Hello, are you still online? I've got one more question with an example on chat

Answer (score 3):

You're putting all the `X` buttons on the same place, on top of `textbox`. Implement some logic that increases Y location of your button. That can be something like this:

```
//... your code here ...
btn1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
//increase Y
// for each control that is inside of textBox, 
// lower your newly created button by count * 18 
// so that btn1.Top will be 0, 18, 36 etc...
btn1.Top = textBox1.Controls.Count * 18; 
textBox1.Controls.Add(btn1);
```

also, as WPFUser noticed, on click on `X` button, you're removing all the X buttons. I'm guessing you should remove last, bottom one

EDIT 2. Each button should remove its corresponding line, like this (didn't test it :))

```
void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //remove right line
    text1.Text = text1.Lines[text1.Controls.IndexOf((Control)sender)].Remove(0);
    //remove button
    text1.Controls.Remove(text1.Controls.OfType<Button>().Last());
}
```

Comment: and he is clearing all Controls when clicking button. Is that correct ? I'm from WPF background, not sure of WF controls VisualTree.

Comment: @WPFUser you're correct, OP should remove that line

Comment: He should only delete the one line with the one button. So each line can be deleted individually.

Comment: @oRole no... because in a scenario where he have 5 rows and clicks on second - that line will be deleted and the button will be removed. But, as line is remove, lower lines will go up. Now we have 4 lines and buttons like X (empty) X X X. So, no X on second line but there is one on fifth, where is no text.

Comment: Hey guys, that's great, Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

@jadolo ,Your code is correct ,It add new button every time but every button will located at same location so those all button will not visible to you, Add assign location property of button like this,so all button are displayed correctly.

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int i = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }


        void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Controls.Clear();
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(1, textBox1.Lines[0].Length + 0);
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(0, textBox1.Lines[0].Length + 0);
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn1 = new Button();
            btn1.Name = "btn"+i++;
            btn1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click_1);
            btn1.Size = new Size(18,18 );
            btn1.Text = "X";
            btn1.Location = new Point(0, i);
            i += 18;
            btn1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            this.textBox1.Controls.Add(btn1);


            string sent = ("\t" + "Testline1");

            textBox1.AppendText(sent);
            textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);


        }
    }
}
```

Design :

[image: Design]

Output :

[image: Output :]

I hope this will help you.